# Dimension of the space of all $n\times n$ matrices $B$ such that $AB=BA$, with $A$ diagonal and having characteristic polynomial $(x-a)^p(x-b)^q$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ diagonal matrix with characteristic polynomial $(x-a)^p(x-b)^q$ where $a $ and $b$ are distinct real numbers. Let $V$ be the real vector space of all $n\times n$ matrices $B$ such that $AB=BA$. Determine the dimension of $V$.

I know for certain that if a matrix $Q$ commutes with a diagonalizable matrix $P$ then $Q$ is also diagonalizable provided $P$ has distinct eigen values.

In here this is not the case.

Comment: It is not true that if Q commutes with a diagonalisable matrix, then, Q is diagonalisable: as you know there are matrices which are not diagonalisable but every matrix commutes with the identity matrix, a diagonal matrix.

Comment: yeah sorry... edited it

Comment: It is advisable to go for $2\times 2$ and $3\times 3$ to get some idea

Comment: After reordering the basis if necessary, you can write the matrix as a diagonal $2 \times 2$ block matrix, with scalar matrices on the diagonal. Now look for $2 \times 2$ block matrices that commute with that one.

Comment: In B, you will have two blocks of orders p and q respectively. So, what is dimension of an $n \times n$ matrix? Hence dim V $= p^2 q^2$.

Comment: @Manasi should n't it be $p^2+q^2$??

Comment: @ Tattwamasi : Thanks.